# RestTemplate Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.HashMap]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, resttemplate

I use Maven + Spring 4.1.0 + Java 6 and I want use RestTemplate().postForEntity(url, request, responseType)

while I execute this code :

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers);
final RestTemplate restTemplate = RestTemplateUtils.createHttpTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity,
            String.class);
```

but I have this error:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.HashMap]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:310)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:270)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:260)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:1)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:596)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:444)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:310)

Comment: and have you defined any converter? May be share your spring config as well please

Comment: thanks but even with the converter, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to old spring Version, so needed to migrate to Spring version 4, and the problem was solved.